# Java generics, can't make constructor with parameter of any Iterable Object

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class signature: `public class LoopIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>`. I have an existing constructor: `public LoopIterator(Iterable<E> iterable){`. I tried to enter in my Main class/Main function the following:

```
LinkedList<String> l= new LinkedList<String>();
l.add("1"); l.add("2"); l.add("3"); l.add("4");
LoopIterator<LinkedList<String>> m= new LoopIterator<LinkedList<String>>(l);
```

But I can't because the constructor expects to get `Iterable<E>` which doesn't comply with `LinkedList<String>`.

So how can I change my constructor/class signature so that I could enter the constructor any Iterable of kind E ?.

Comment: LinkedList implements Iterable...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, LinkedList implements Iterable and E is the type of object returned while iterating (viz. String).

So, you need...

```
LoopIterator<String> m = new LoopIterator<String>( l);
```

and the compiler should be happier.

Answer (score 0):

```
LoopIterator<LinkedList<String>> m= new LoopIterator<LinkedList<String>>(l);
```

On the left side you define that `m.next()` will return instances of `LinkedList<String>` but one the right side you pass something which iterate over `String` instances. So that's a contradiction!

Just say what you want! `m.next()` will return instances of `String`:

```
LoopIterator<String> m = new LoopIterator<String>( l);
```